# memory management for dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following code , i don't understand the scenario behind this please any one can explain.

```
import sys
data={}
print sys.getsizeof(data)
######output is 280
data={ 1:2,2:1,3:2,4:5,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,0:0,11:11,12:12,13:13,14:14,15:15}
print sys.getsizeof(data)
######output is 1816
data={1:2,2:1,3:2,4:5,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,0:0,11:11,12:12,13:13,14:14,15:15,16:16}
print sys.getsizeof(data)
##### output is 1048
```

if we increase the len of dictionary then it should increase on size in memory but it decreases why ?

Comment: It's not like so in my machine, can you pls test this in a terminal!

Comment: Note that this only works when creating a new dictionary, e.g if you do `data[16] = 16` for the second one, then the size is still 1816. `sys.getsizeof` returns the size of the object, and not the objects it contains. Moreover, the reason the last dict is smaller in size than the second has to do with hash tables in Python. Smaller dicts result to more collisions, so I suppose this has something to do with it. I urge you to check out [Brandon Rhodes' talk "The mighty dictionary"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68), for more in-depth explanation.

Comment: i had done this on ipython  (mac 64 bit )

Comment: I had noticed that when len(data)=22 memory size become 3352 when len(data)=32 memory size again decreases and become 1816 for every 10 element interval its decreases and increases in the multiples of 1536 so when len(data)=42  then 6424 , which is 3352+1536*2 . but still not find correct scenario why this is follows by python .

Answer (score 0):

> `getsizeof()` calls the object’s `__sizeof__` method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

Windows x64 - If did like below:

```
data={ 1:2,2:1,3:2,4:5,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,0:0,11:11,12:12,13:13,14:14,15:15}
print sys.getsizeof(data)
print data
data[16]=16
print sys.getsizeof(data)
print data
```

printed:

```
1808
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15}
1808
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16}
```

But I indeed noticed same behavior when rewriting data dictionary as you mentioned:

```
272  #empty data dict
1808 # 15 elements in data dict
1040 # 16 elements in data dict
```